# Why am I getting a syntax error when I enter "from sklearn.model_selection import"?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Following the book "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python" I have tried every exercise using Jupyter Notebooks. When I inserted the following code to split data I get a syntax error for the first line, hence I can't go further. What is wrong with line 1? Thanks

```
from sklearn.model_selection import
train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(iris_dataset['data'], 
            iris_dataset)['target'], random_state = 0)
```

Comment: Can you please post the error too, from what I can guess the error might be due to your `train_test_split` in the next line, it must be in the same line just after the `import` keyword

Comment: You can't just stick random line breaks into your code in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import should be in a **single** line, i.e.:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

The same holds true for the statement after `=` - it should be in the same line:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris_dataset['data'], 
                                   iris_dataset['target'], random_state = 0)
```

As already hinted at in the comments, line breaks in Python are important, and you cannot just use them as you see fit.

In short, and in order to avoid opening similar questions for whatever code comes below what you have posted here, whenever you get syntax errors like these, try moving things in the same lines...

Comment: Thanks for your help. The final end parenthesis was not necessary as well. Learning Python as a 74 yo physician has not been easy